# Is there a way to ask Jersey to not make special symbols url-safe?

Tags: java, url, jersey, salesforce

I'm trying to access a REST webservice from SalesForce from my java application.
I'm using Jersey to make the webservice call.

```
private String getRegisterId(String registerName, String accessToken) throws JSONException, BusinessException {
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    config.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
    Client client = Client.create(config);

    WebResource wr = client.resource(salesforeceUrl + "/data/v31.0/query");
    JSONObject register = wr //
            .queryParam("q", "SELECT+Id+FROM+HealthData_Register__c+WHERE+name+=+'" + registerName + "'+AND+IsDeleted+=+false") //
            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION.getValue(), "Bearer " + accessToken) //
            .get(JSONObject.class);

    JSONArray records = register.getJSONArray("records");
        return records.getJSONObject(0).getString("Id");

}
```

The problem I have is that Jersey is so nice that it changes the + symbol to %2B and the + symbol to %3D for my queryParam but SalesForce doesn't like this.
It also does this for the header. If my accessToken contains a special character I will get an 401 (UNAUTHORIZED) response.

Is there a way to ask Jersey to not make special symbols url-safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a GET request it's correct that the query params are url-encoded.

Why do you put the symbol + instead of spaces in the query? Did you try putting just the spaces? Is really the server expecting a + symbol instead of spaces?

Comment: it works when changing the + to a space. I took the + from there example but this was using curl.